# Filter and stristr(): find all the words except the first

Tags: php, arrays, function, collections, filter

When filtering the items that are going to be shown, if the word that I want to search is the first one of the item, it does not find it. Example: I have the title, "**tomorrow will be a sunny day**". If I look for **tomorrow**, this does not find it, if I look for **sunny** or **day**, it does. How can I do to search in the whole sentence including the first word?
This is the code:

```
    $url_noticias = 'storage/json/es/noticia.json';
    $noticias = json_decode(file_get_contents($url_noticias), true);
    $noticias = array_filter($noticias);

    $data['noticias'] = collect($noticias)->filter(function ($item) use ($request){
        return stristr($item['title'], $request->texto, true);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it could be problem of the treating 0 (zero) as false.

If the string is on first position, ie. position 0 and the test is if it was found or not, then the zero value is interpreted as false. But in this case it was successfully found on zero position.

To avoid such behaviour do not compare only values but the type as well.

```
(0 == false) -> true
```

but

```
(0 === false) -> false
```

so the testing occurrence should be like `($position !== false)`

Return boolean instead of the position:

```
return (stristr($item['title'], $request->texto, true) !== false) ? true : false;
```

**Edit**
As @Progrock correctly pointed out, the function `stristr` does not return a position, it returns a substring or false.

So the root cause of *not finding* a word at the beginning of the string is a bit elsewhere.

The function `stristr` does the case insensitive search and if string is found, and the *tommorow* is found, then the returned value is a `string`. And the string is treated as *true*, so the comparison works as follow:

```
 ("string" == false) -> false
```

However the `stristr` is called with the third optional parameter that is set to `true`. [According to the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) the `stristr` function returns the part of the haystack before the first occurrence of the needle (excluding needle).
And because the *tomorrow* is at the beginning of the string *tomorrow will be a sunny day* then the returned value is empty string which is interpreted as false:

```
("" == false) -> true
```

Conclusion
if you keep third parameter as `true` problems with empty string occurs with words at the beginning of the string, if you set it to `false` or remove it (it is optional parameter with default value false) then the problem with returned empty string occurs with word at the end of the string.

So the proposed solution in original answer handle both cases regardless using true/false as the third parameter.

Comment: Thanks @ino, now I understand it but How can I implement it in my code?

Comment: `stristr` does not return a position, it returns a substring or false.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Progrock

Comment: @Progrock thanks for pointing it out! I have extended my answer to reflect the _real_ returned value.

Comment: It looks as if you mistook stristr with strpos.  Why not just drop the first part of your answer?  Not sure why the OP called stristr with the third param, if they hadn't then it's likely most strings would have evaluated to true.  Unless say they were searching for a 0 that occurred at the very end of the string.  Because some strings evaluate to false when cast to a boolean, it's better to check for a return of false.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$haystack = 'Tomorrow will be a sunny day';
$needles  = ['tomorrow', 'foo', 'sunny', 'day'];

foreach($needles as $needle) {
    if (stristr($haystack, $needle) !== false)
        printf ("'%s' found in '%s'\n", $needle, $haystack);
    else
        printf("'%s' not found in '%s'\n", $needle, $haystack);
}
```

Output:

```
'tomorrow' found in 'Tomorrow will be a sunny day'
'foo' not found in 'Tomorrow will be a sunny day'
'sunny' found in 'Tomorrow will be a sunny day'
'day' found in 'Tomorrow will be a sunny day'
```